# Find unique values of groupby/transform without None

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

The starting point is this kind of dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'author': ['Jack', 'Steve', 'Greg', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Greg', 'Greg'], 'country':['USA', None, None, 'USA', 'Germany', 'France', 'France'], 'c':np.random.randn(7), 'd':np.random.randn(7)})

  author  country         c         d
0  Jack   USA     -2.594532  2.027425
1  Steve  None    -1.104079 -0.852182
2  Greg   None    -2.356956 -0.450821
3  Jack   USA     -0.910153 -0.734682
4  Steve  Germany  1.025113  0.441512
5  Greg   France   0.218085  1.369443
6  Greg   France   0.254485  0.322768
```

The desired output is one column or multiple columns with countrys of a author.

```
0    [USA]          
1    [Germany]
2    [France] 
3    [USA]          
4    [Germany]
5    [France] 
6    [France]
```

It has not to be a list, but my closest solution for now gives a list as output.
It could be seperated columns.

```
df.groupby('author')['country'].transform('unique')

0    [USA]          
1    [None, Germany]
2    [None, France] 
3    [USA]          
4    [None, Germany]
5    [None, France] 
6    [None, France]
```

Is there a easy way of deleting None out of this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove missing values with [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), call [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) and create new column by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new'] = df['author'].map(df['country'].dropna().groupby(df['author']).unique())
print (df)
  author  country         c         d        new
0   Jack      USA  0.453358 -1.983282      [USA]
1  Steve     None  0.011792  0.383322  [Germany]
2   Greg     None -1.551810  0.308982   [France]
3   Jack      USA  1.646301  0.040245      [USA]
4  Steve  Germany -0.211451  0.841131  [Germany]
5   Greg   France  1.049269 -0.813806   [France]
6   Greg   France -1.244549  1.009006   [France]
```